# Need to figure out how to output a equation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

So I have 3 slots to input the information and need help outputting an equation.

With starting size: 4, step: 1, and limit: 9 the output would look something like:

A 4 inch square pizza has 16 square inches of pizza

A 5 inch square pizza has 25 square inches of pizza

A 6 inch square pizza has 36 square inches of pizza

A 7 inch square pizza has 49 square inches of pizza

A 8 inch square pizza has 64 square inches of pizza

Another example - 
With starting size: 4, step: 3, and limit: 15 the output would look something like:

A 4 inch square pizza has 16 square inches of pizza

A 7 inch square pizza has 49 square inches of pizza

A 10 inch square pizza has 100 square inches of pizza

A 13 inch square pizza has 169 square inches of pizza

When i hit calculate now with nothing written in it says  A inch square pizza has square inches of pizza.

Just need help on what to write with the equation

So you would need to input the Starting size - ______

Steps _______

And Limit  __________

What would the equation look like for implementing this for JavaScript?

My code  -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DreStone.css">

    <title>Pizza A23</title> 


    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
<script src="util.js"></script>

<script> 
var z={}; 


/**********************
EVENT HANDLERS
***********************/

z.calculate = function()
{ pizza = parseInt(u.eid("ssize").value);
  limit = parseInt(u.eid("slimit").value);
  step =  parseInt(u.eid("steps").value);



u.eid("output").innerHTML = "";


     {
     u.eid("output").innerHTML += "A "  + " inch square pizza has" + " square inches of pizza"; 
     } 
}
/**********************
WINDOW.ONLOAD
***********************/
window.onload = function()
{
//--- ADDING EVENT LISTENERS
u.eid("calc").addEventListener('click', z.calculate); 
} 
</script> 

</head> 

<body>
<h1> Pizza A23</h1>

Starting size: <input id="ssize" type="text">
Step Size: <input id="steps" type="text">
Size Limit: <input id="slimit" type="text">
<br><br>
<button id="calc" type="button">Calculate</button>
<hr>
<div id="output">
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Everything about the code works so far just need to know how to put the equation after u.eid("output").innerHTML +=

Comment: `u.eid("output").innerHTML += "A "  + " inch square pizza has" + " square inches of pizza"; ` You need to insert the variables in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need a for loop to list each pizza. Javascript lets you join variables and string together using +. So you can do something like `"A " + i + " inch pizza"`. Putting this together you want something like:

```
z.calculate = function() { 
    pizza = parseInt(u.eid("ssize").value);
    limit = parseInt(u.eid("slimit").value);
    step =  parseInt(u.eid("steps").value);

    u.eid("output").innerHTML = "";

    for(var i=pizza; i < limit; i=i+step )
    {
         var size = i * i; // work out square size
         u.eid("output").innerHTML += "A " + i + " inch square pizza has" + size + " square inches of pizza"; 
    }
}
```